# Make an equivalent to Excel's =PERCENTRANK.EXC function in R?

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula

I was wondering how would I convert the Excel's Percentile rank exclusive function in R. I found [a technique here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/computing-percentile-rank-in-r) which is like this:

```r
true_df <- data.frame(some_column= c(24516,7174,13594,33838,40000))

percentilerank<-function(x){
  rx<-rle(sort(x))
  smaller<-cumsum(c(0, rx$lengths))[seq(length(rx$lengths))]
  larger<-rev(cumsum(c(0, rev(rx$lengths))))[-1]
  rxpr<-smaller/(smaller+larger)
  rxpr[match(x, rx$values)]
}
dfr<-percentilerank(true_df$some_column)

#output which is similar to =PERCENTRANK.INC and NOT =PERCENTRANK.EXC
#[1] 0.50 0.00 0.25 0.75 1.00
```

But it is for `=PERCENTRANK.INC` equivalent in R. According to info popup in Excel, a `=PERCENTRANK.INC` takes (array, x-value of rank, [significance-optional]) and returns percentage rank inclusive of the first (0%) and last (100%) values in the array.

`=PERCENTRANK.EXC` is similar to its counterpart but it returns percentage rank exclusive of the first and last values in the array. Meaning not 0% or 100%.

Here is a small example using Excel to show difference:

[image]

When I apply the above R function it gives me the output similar to `PERCENTRANK.INC($A$32:$A$36,A32)` column. How can I achieve this? I'm new to R.

Comment: We don't want no steenking pictures in SO.

Comment: Hello, I have checked this meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314547/… because I couldn't post my little excel sheet. So posted the snippet. Sorry about that. I fix the R code to make it a reproducible.

Comment: Hello @G.Grothendieck I checked that out before posting. Unfortunately, it was also the inclusive version, similar to the first column in picture and the output in question. You happen to know the exclusive version? I would rather go `dplyr` route .

Comment: Have transferred my comment to answer and added exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# inclusive
percent_rank(x)

# exclusive
percent_rank(c(-Inf, Inf, x))[-(1:2)]
```

Comment: Oh wow, much nicer than what I did. Thank you very much! EDIT: I picked this as  an answer, it was saying in my post that I would be able to pick in 2 days. Sorry. Gave you the credit! Stay safe brother.

Comment: @WolfgangBagdnow: Type `dplyr::percent_rank; dplyr::minrank` to see how it's done. Might also answer your question posed above.

Comment: Sorry this is bit late. Thank you IRTFM.

Answer (score 1):

I messed around with the code and got this:

```r
true_df <- data.frame(some_column= c(24516,7174,13594,33838,40000))

percentilerank<-function(x){
  rx<-rle(sort(x))
  smaller<-cumsum(c(!0, rx$lengths))[seq(length(rx$lengths))]
  larger<-rev(cumsum(c(0, rev(rx$lengths))))
  rxpr<-smaller/(smaller+larger)
  rxpr[match(x, rx$values)]
}

dfr<-percentilerank(true_df$some_column)

#output is now matches =PERCENTRANK.EXC 
#[1] 0.5000000 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.8333333
```

Since the 0 and 100% are not included in the percentile. I changed the line `smaller<-cumsum(c(0....` to `smaller<-cumsum(c(!0....` and similarly to get rid of 100% where I took out [-1] from line `larger<-...[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

This is how to replicate PERCENTRANK.EXC in other native Excel formulas:

= Round(Rank/(N + 1) - 0.05%, 3)

Maybe that will help someone.

The 3 corresponds to the default level of significance in PERCENTRANK.EXC. Change as needed.